# Load assembly into application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mef, strong-typing, strongly-typed-view

I am trying to implement a plugin application into my MVC application, I have managed to sort out the view engines and inject a new controller from the assembly into application with the use of MEf.

However the assembly I am trying to load also has a strongly type module that I would like to inject into the plugin application I am loading the assembly as follow:

[image]

I can tell the assembly is loaded into current appdomain but still I am getting following error:

Compilation Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

> Compiler Error Message:  CS0246: The type or namespace name 'cars'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some hint.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In what situation you receive mentioned error?

Comment: I get this error when calling a view with the controller that has been loaded with MEF from the same assembly that i have loaded at application start. basically this assembly contains both controller and strongly typed module. i load the controller with MEF and  MefControllerFactory. and it works fine so controller has been recognized by MVC application. but it can't find the strongly typed assembly. hope it make sense. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Paths without a drive identifier are treated as relative, so it may be that the relative path isn't where you expect it to be.

Comment: thanks for comments, yes the path is current because i can see that the Assembly is loaded into app-domain. just to mention that the assembly is located outside the bin folder.

Comment: Try using a.GetExportedTypes() instead of a.GetTypes().

Comment: More detail about the exception itself would be helpful (i.e. name and stack trace)

Comment: thank you very much for replay, i have tried GetExportedTypes but it didn't work );

Comment: The fact it is a compiler error instead of a runtime error suggests to me that you are trying to use the namespace "cars" somewhere in your program without having the namespace defined by any referenced dlls. So you are either missing a reference or using "cars" when you shouldn't be. What line does the exception occur? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7xf6dxs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i think you are right, but is that possible to add namespace/reference programmatically to an application?

Comment: You don't need to 'use' a namespace if you are dynamically loading types. You control the type by using its type object to create a reference and then by casting it into something it implements/inherits. To make things easier for writing plugins it is best to provide a library/API with classes and interfaces for any plugins to use to communicate with your program.

Comment: well that's correct, with the interfaces i can make communication with my application but i am looking for a way to load external assemblies without using interfaces, i think it is not possible. thank you very much for you help, i relay do  appreciate it.

Comment: You can just poll for the loaded assembly's types and their methods, but it's much easier if the types in the assembly implement interfaces or classes that the main program knows about since it can then work with them manually instead of invoking methods using reflection all the time. If for some reason you can't expose a full API, then you can carry on doing what you are doing and just use reflection with methods like type.GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue lies in the inclusion of a non-referenced library, though in your case as you are trying to dynamically load a library the solution is to remove the the using directive.

To properly manage plugins you should expose a common API in the form of a library.
The API should provide interfaces and classes that are abstract enough that they can be used by any plugin to properly register itself. They should expose enough to perform the actions you would expect or allow (i.e. changing the interface, adding a way to handle certain types of content), but should not expose large amounts of inner workings or secure information.

There are two ways you can define a plugin, you can have them as .exes or .dlls.

If you define them as .exes you can make them accept classes defined in the plugin API that they then use to register themselves. Example:

Main Program:

```
void LoadPlugin(string fullPath)
{
Assembly assembly = Assembly.FromFile(fullPath);
//class that provides methods for registering plugins
IPluginRegistrationService registration = new PluginRegistrationService();
assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null,new object[] { registration });
}
```

Plugin:

```
static void main(IPluginRegistrationService registration)
{
//do registration work
//for example:
//registration.RegisterUIPlugin(new UIPluginInfo("plugin name"));
}
```

If you define them as .dlls, the program itself must search for and instantiate classes that implement an interface/class that defines the plugin's entry. Example:

MainProgram:

```
void LoadPlugin(string fullPath)
{
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
foreach (Module module in assembly.GetModules())
{
foreach (Type type in module.GetTypes())
{
if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IPlugin)))
{ 
//poll constructors and instantiate type
//do work to load plugin based on values
}
}
}
}
```

Plugin:

```
public class CarPlugin : IPlugin
{
//implement IPlugin members to expose
//information such as name 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you solution, it is very helpful. i do appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. Out of interest, this is also how some games achieve DLC. MVC seems to be heavily reliant on reflection.